# User with double account

Tags: support, users

I found a user with 2 accounts, which alternate to repeat similar questions with slight variations. Is this allowed?

**EDITED**

Questions:

[split-string-three-to-three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462969/split-string-three-to-three)
[why-in-array-all-indices-are-0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7463838/why-in-array-all-indices-are-0)

Users:

[Jennifer Anthony](https://stackoverflow.com/users/924353/jennifer-anthony)
[Selena Winter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/926128/selena-winter)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is this allowed?

Usually no - that sounds like a user deliberately trying to circumvent a low quality filter block. It could also be an innocent mix-up. In any case, the accounts need to be looked at.

The best solution is to flag a question for moderator attention, and including a link to the suspected duplicate user profile.