# Flagged potential double account - got declined because double accounts are not forbidden

Tags: support, flags, user-accounts, declined-flags

Today (Wednesday) I flagged a question for the following reason (names anonymized) :

> Most probably again a double account of user ******** (stackoverflow.com/users/*******/******). This question uses the same wording and same data like one posted by by a user named "*******" at matlab central:http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/******. This time, however, the questions are not identical but the similarity is still intriguing.

The flag got declined with the following justification:

> declined - as long as no cross voting etc is involved having multiple accounts is not forbidden

However, before flagging I searched MSO for the SO double account policy and got the impression that double accounts are not permitted (see for instance, here: [User with double account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106608/user-with-double-account)).

Moreover, when I flagged a potential double account two days earlier (on Monday), the flag got approved and the accounts in question were merged (it was the same user, by the way).

**So, why is having a double account allowed on Wednesdays but not on Mondays?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are no rules against having more than one account.

There *are* rules against using another account to break the rules. No sock-puppeting, voting rings or ban evasions allowed.